# How to get value of any attribute of HTML code that saved in variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

If I have this variable `X` that holds `HTML` code

```
<form ... >
<p>..</p>
<input name=A value=B>
<input name=B value=C>
.....
</form>
```

how can I get the `value` of the `input B` by calling the `variable` ?
Is that possible ?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your code sample. Can you show us some javaScript?

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you give your HTML element an id and then use the jQuery `attr` method.

```
var element = $('#id');
console.log(element.attr('value'));
```

If you don't want to add an ID, you can do:

```
var element = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1];
console.log(element.attr('value'));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a javascript string of html like this

```
var X = "<form ... >
<p>..</p>
<input name=\"A\" value=\"B\">
<input name=\"B\" value=\"C\">
.....
</form>";
```

The most reliable way to get at the value of those inputs would be to insert the HTML into the DOM which would cause the browser to parse the string as HTML and allow you to get the values via DOM methods

```
var div = document.createElement("div");  
div.style.display = "none";
document.body.appendChild(div);
div.innerHTML = X;
var valueB = div.getElementsByName("B")[0].value;
```